# Excel как сортировать цифры и слова

Tags: excel, vba

нужно открыть текстовый документ и рассортировать слова в одну колонну и цифры в другую которые находятся в тектовом документе каждый в своем ряду с помощью excel vba.

```
Public Sub bbb()

Workbooks("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Cells().Clear

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim skaitli As String

i = 1
d = 1
If fd.Show = -1 Then
    filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    Open filename For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, st
        If Int(Val(st)) = Val(st) Then
            Cells(i, 1) = st
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Cells(d, 2) = st
            d = d + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
End If
Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Нужно по идее поменять только строку     `If Int(Val(st)) = Val(st) Then`
Незнаю как зделать , все уже перепробовал .

Comment: If IsNumeric(st) Then

Comment: Лучше бы привели пример исходных данных и желаемого результата, а то не совсем как-то понятно исходя из описания